# How to calculate distance of steiner point in Euclidean Steiner Tree?

Tags: metric-spaces

The euclidean steiner tree for 3 vertices (a,b,c) can be constructed by adding a steiner point (s) connecting 3 edges (as, bs, cs). One way to define the distance of edge (as, bs, cs) is by calculating the gromov product of 3 vertices, such that

d(a,s) = 0.5 * ( d(a,c) + d(a,b) - d(b,c) )
d(b,s) = 0.5 * ( d(b,c) + d(b,a) - d(a,c) )
d(c,s) = 0.5 * ( d(a,c) + d(b,c) - d(a,b) )

May I know is there other method to calculate the distance of steiner point from each set of vertices?

Comment: Title asks for coordinates of Steiner point, body asks for distances from Steiner point to vertices. These are different, no? Please edit so title and body agree.

Comment: alright, calculating distance of steiner point from each vertices are what I am trying to look at..

Comment: The formulas you've given look amazingly simple. Why do you want another method?

Comment: did you find an answer ?

Comment: I did't explore this topic for a while.